# questions about generics of doubles and complex types in c

Tags: c, generics, macros, free, void-pointers

In the c programming language, there are no such things known as generics, but you can cheat your way of working with multiple types with macros and void pointers. For example lets say that we want a structure, called wrapper that simply stores a value of any type and any operations done, on the wrapper don't require anything to do with its value.

## Using Macros

```c
#define WRAPPER(TYPE) typedef struct {##TYPE value;} wrapper_##TYPE
```

Then the user can just paste `WRAPPER(int);` on top of their code and they will have access to `wrapper_int` or even paste it multiple times with different types.

## Using Void*

```c
typedef struct {void* value;} wrapper;
```

Now the user can cast their value to a `void*` and lets say they want to use an `int`. They need to cast their int to a `void*` pointer. This is how functions such as `malloc`, `realloc` and `calloc` work.

## Problems

I'm creating a library for many things and one thing that I am currently creating is a dynamic array that works on any type and is also automatically freed.

To automatically free the arrays. I have created static global variables, one is an array storing the array and the other is the length of that array. Then using gnu c `__attribute__((constructor))`, I am freeing both the arrays and the array containing the arrays.

This approach simply doesn't allow me to use the macro way of doing things, since all code needs to be defined in the library c file and not even the header.

So stuck to the `void*` solution. It works for many different types, even including strings, but `float`, `double` and complex types(structures, unions and enums) don't work, since you can't cast them to a `void*.

I read serval stackoverflow questions about the same question. In general, I found out that you can't cast `double` to `void*`, but you can cast `double*` to `void*`.

Using just an int.

```c
#include "kstring.h"
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, const string* argv)
{
    array a = create(0);

    for (usize i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        append(&a, (type)(usize)(int)parse(argv[i]));
    }

    for (usize i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        print("%d\n", (int)(usize)(a.elements[i]));
}
```

```
./build/app 1 2 3 2 1
1
2
3
2
1
```

It even works on strings.

```c
#include "kstring.h"
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, const string* argv)
{
    array a = create(0);

    for (usize i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        append(&a, (type)argv[i]);
    }

    for (usize i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        print("%s\n", (string)(a.elements[i]));
}
```

```
./build/app X Y Z Y X
X
Y
Z
Y
X
```

But not on doubles, or any of the types mentioned.

```c
#include "kstring.h"
#include "array.h"

int main(int argc, const string* argv)
{
    array a = create(0);

    for (usize i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        double x = parse(argv[i]);
        append(&a, (type)&x);
    }

    for (usize i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        print("%lf\n", *((double*)(a.elements[i])));
}
```

```
./build/app 1.1 2.1 3.3 1.2 1.1
1.100000
1.100000
1.100000
1.100000
1.100000
```

This is due, to the fact that it's storing the pointer to x and with each iteration the value is changing. So the value is what ever the latest value. How can I make this work?

`type` is just an alias to `void*`. Most of the code is using stuff from `kstring.h` and `array.h` which are defined by myself. All functions such as `parse` and ... work correctly.

The problem is not from my library, rather how to work with my libraries' generic system. I've seen the source code of multiple other libraries and they were doing the same thing.

Comment: Your array library needs to know the element size and use `memcpy` to copy things into the array.  You'll also need a `get` function returning a pointer to the *i*th element.

Comment: Can you please provide a more in depth explanation, with an example

Comment: "In the c programming language, there are no such things known as generics" --> research `_Generic`, since C99.

Comment: `WRAPPER(TYPE)` fails when the type have a space like `long long`.

Comment: "Now the user can cast their value to a void*" fails when the type loses info in the conversion as with function pointers, wide integer types, long double, complex, etc.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my exact problem is how to make it, so it won't fail on those types

Comment: As @dbush [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645829/questions-about-generics-of-doubles-and-complex-types-in-c?noredirect=1#comment131757284_74645829), use `memcpy()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I've read about it and it's like `strcpy`, but can you please provide an example on how it can be used here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change your library to store arbitrary types.  The main thing is that it needs to know the size of the element so that it can take the address of whatever the type is and use `memcpy` to copy the bytes over.

For example:

```
struct array {
    int length;
    int esize;
    unsigned char *elements;
};

struct array create(int esize, length)
{
    struct array a;
    a.length = length;
    a.esize = esize;
    a.elements = malloc(esize * length);
    return a;
}

void append(struct array *a, const void *data)
{
    a->length++;
    a->elements = realloc(a->elements, a->esize * a->length);
    memcpy(a->elements + (a->esize * (a->length - 1)), data, a->esize);
}

void *get(struct array *a, int idx)
{
    return a->elements + (a->esize * idx);
}
```

Don't forget to add error checking for all calls to `malloc` and `realloc`.

Comment: is there a way of implementing this so that `array->elements` can be treated like a normal array, with `[]`?

Comment: or at least maybe a `set` function?

Comment: @KianFakheriAghdam Array indexing is out of the question (unless you want to access individual bytes) but you could implement a `set` function similar to the `append` function.